# Storing Frequency Count of Simulation Function Output in R

Tags: r, data-structures, simulation

I have a program where I am running a simulation function for a large number of iterations.  I'm stuck, however, on what I expected to be the easiest part: figuring out how to store frequency counts of the function's results.

The simulation function itself is complicated, but is analogous to the R's `sample()` function.  A large amount of data goes in, and the function outputs a vector containing a subset of elements.

```
x <- c("red", "blue", "yellow", "orange", "green", "black", "white", "pink")

run_simulation <- function(input_data, iterations = 100){
  for (i in 1:iterations){
    result <- sample(input_data, 3, replace=FALSE)
    results <- ????
  }
}

run_simulation(x)
```

My question is what is the best (most efficient and R-like) data structure to store the frequency counts of the results of the function inside the simulation loop.  As you might be able to tell from the `for` loop, my background is in languages like Python, where I would create a dict keyed by tuples that increments every time a particular combination is output:

```
counts[results_tuple] = counts.get(results_tuple, 0) + 1
```

However, there is no equivalent dict/hashmap type structure in R, and I've often found that trying to emulate other languages in R is a recipe for ugly and inefficient code.  (Right now I am converting the output vector to a string and appending it to a result list that I count later with `table()`, but that is very memory inefficient for a high number of iterations over a function that has a limited number of possible output vectors.)

To be clear, here is kind of output I want:

```
               Result Freq
   black, pink, green    8
     blue, red, white    7
    black, pink, blue    7
   blue, green, black    5
     blue, green, red    4
   green, blue, white    3
   pink, green, white    3
   white, blue, green    1
   white, orange, red    1
yellow, black, orange    1
  yellow, blue, green    1
```

I don't care about the frequency of any particular element, only the set.  And I don't care about the order of output, just the frequency.

Any advice is appreciated!

Comment: Posted an answer to immediately realize that it was also in your description! Not too original then! And, should read more carefully the post... Anyway, response deleted. If I come with a more original way will post again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could also use an `environment` (which does in fact use a hash table). In this way you do not need to enumerate all outcomes of your simulation as you are anyways just interested in the counts:

```
runSimulation <- function(input.size = 300L, iterations = 100L) {
   x <- paste0("E", 1L:input.size)
   results <- new.env(hash = TRUE)
   for (i in 1:iterations){
      result <- sample(x, 3, replace = FALSE)
      nam <- paste0(sort(result), collapse = ".")
      if (exists(nam, results)) {
         results[[nam]] <- results[[nam]] + 1
      } else {
         assign(nam, 1, envir = results)
      }
   }
   l <- as.list(results)
   d <- data.frame(tuple = names(l), count = unlist(l))
   rownames(d) <- NULL
   d
}
```

However, timewise this is comparable to the solution using `table`.

Comment: This gets at exactly what I want -- not precomputing all possible results is essential given the size of my input data.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a `data.table` (a juiced-up `data.frame` implementation) that uses possible values as key. They require a specific syntax, but are very efficient.

Here is how I would go about it. Matching simulation outputs back to the index requires sorting it, so I saved it under a new variable:

```
require(data.table)

x <- c("red", "blue", "yellow", "orange", "green", "black", "white", "pink")

run_simulation <- function(input_data, iterations = 100){

  # generate set of all possible outputs
  possible_values <- sort(input_data)  ## needed to match simulations

  # combn() seems to preserve input order
  # have to sort each column from combn() output if this is not guaranteed
  results <- as.data.table(t(combn(possible_values, 3)))
  setnames(results, c("first", "second", "third"))
  results[, count:=0]  ## initiate counts column
  setkey(results, first, second, third)  ## use index columns as table key

  for (i in 1:iterations){
    result <- sample(input_data, 3, replace=FALSE)
    result_sorted <- t(sort(result))  ## t() needed to specify it's a row
    colnames(result_sorted) <- c('first', 'second', 'third')
    result_sorted <- as.data.table(result_sorted)
    results[result_sorted, count:=count + 1]
  }
  return(results)
}
```

Most of the lines after generation are needed to get the vector into the right format for `data.table` to look up the correct row. This may be overkill for a small number of possible combinations, but should pay dividends if the possible set is larger.

Comment: This is great.  One question: is there a way to avoid filling the data.table with all possible combinations?  (I.e. the line `results <- as.data.table(t(combn(possible_values, 3)))`.  With my actual input data this would be a huge number of possibilities, but the simulation function only outputs a small fraction of the possible outputs.  Maybe something like `if (!exists(results[result_sorted])){results[result_sorted]$count <- 0 }`

Comment: That is possible, but not advisable. In R it's a good idea to preallocate the size of the object you intend to use (variables need contiguous memory). If you don't want the zeros, I suggest removing them at the end with something like this: `return(results[count > 0])`

Comment: Realized the assignment to `current_count` was not necessary and removed the line

Comment: In reality my input vector has a few hundred elements, and the output has about 10.  That makes the total number of combinations 300^10 ish, which makes pre-allocating all possibilities infeasible.

Comment: If the number of samples is manageable, then simply storing all simulations in a big pre-allocated object and summarizing at the end may be the way to go. Pre-allocation is key, because extending your object causes it to be rewritten.

Answer (score 1):

The following is a short solution using base R which seems to give fairly quick execution times.

```
 run_simulation <- function(input_data, iterations = 100){
 Results  <-  replicate(iterations, paste0(sort(sample(input_data, 3, replace=FALSE)),collapse=", ")  )
 results <- as.data.frame(table(Results) )
 }
```

run_simulation(x) gives

```
                  Results Freq
 1     black, blue, green    2
 2    black, blue, orange    2
 3      black, blue, pink    6
 4       black, blue, red    6
 5     black, blue, white    2
 6   black, green, orange    3
 7     black, green, pink    1
 8      black, green, red    1
```

Benchmarking this for 100, 1,000, 10,000, and 100,000 iterations shows that the times increase linearly with the number of iterations which seems desirable.  Also the total time for 100,000 iterations is about 2,200 milliseconds or 2.2 secs.  You describe your simulation as complicated using a great deal of data so it may well be that the total time doing your simulation significantly exceeds the time spent in this bit of code tabulating the results.

```
 library(microbenchmark)

 microbenchmark(run_simulation(x,iterations=100), run_simulation(x,iterations=1000), run_simulation(x,iterations=10000), run_simulation(x,iterations=100000), times=100)

 Unit: milliseconds
                                   expr         min          lq      median          uq        max neval
    run_simulation(x, iterations = 100)    2.352262    2.447647    2.488282    2.573545   71.96314   100
    run_simulation(x, iterations = 1000)   19.161997   19.751702   20.476572   24.411885   90.42650   100
    run_simulation(x, iterations = 10000)  193.688216  208.453087  217.130138  226.166201  289.13177   100
    run_simulation(x, iterations = 1e+05) 2012.773904 2125.986609 2169.870885 2236.038487 2426.02379   100
```